# How to pass a variable from remote ssh connection to other stages in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a groovy script for a Jenkins pipeline and am struggling to find how to pass a variable across stages when the variable is obtained from a remote ssh connection.
I found Example 1 and Example 2 on this site and I want to merge them together as seen in "My attempt" below. Note that the output of the file on the remote server is 4. I'm trying pass 4 to a_var.

**Example 1: works fine. SSH connection. This reads the file and outputs value to the Jenkins console**

```js
def sshCredId = 'myid_cred'
def sshUser = 'myid'
def sshServer = 'myserver'

pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker-maven-slave' }
  stages {
    stage('one') {
      steps {
        script {
          sshagent([sshCredId]){ 
              sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${sshUser}@${sshServer} cat /mydir/myfile.csv" 
          } 
        }
      }
    }
    stage('two') {
      steps {
        echo "something" 
      }
    }
    stage('three') {
      steps {
        echo "do stuff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example 2: works fine. This passes a parameter across stages**

```js
  pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'docker-maven-slave'
        }
        parameters {
            string(name: 'a_var', defaultValue: '')
        }
        stages {
            stage("one") {
                 steps {
                    script {
                    tmp_param =  sh (script: 'echo something', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    env.a_var = tmp_param
                    }
                  }
            }
            stage("two") {
                steps {
                  echo "${env.a_var}"
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

**My attempt: stage two output is null. I'm expecting '4' **

```js
def sshCredId = 'myid_cred'
def sshUser = 'myid'
def sshServer = 'myserver'

pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker-maven-slave' }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'a_var', defaultValue: 'nothing')
  }
  stages {
    stage('one') {
      steps {
        script {
            tmp_param=sshagent([sshCredId]){ 
              sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${sshUser}@${sshServer} cat /mydir/myfile.csv" 
            }
            env.a_var=tmp_param
        }
      }
    }
    stage('two') {
      steps {
        echo "${env.a_var}" 
      }
    }
    stage('three') {
      steps {
        echo "do stuff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be simple. Try 
 sshagent([sshCredId]){ 
              env.a_var = sh  (script: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${sshUser}@${sshServer} cat /mydir/myfile.csv', returnStdout: true).trim()
 }

Comment: yes! that worked with a small change from single to double quotes around the ssh statement.  sshagent([sshCredId]){ env.a_var = sh (script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${sshUser}@${sshServer} cat /mydir/myfile.csv", returnStdout: true).trim() }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the answer based on comments and feedback from MayJoAnneBeth
Try below snippet

```
sshagent([sshCredId]){ 
env.a_var = sh (script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${sshUser}@${sshServer} cat /mydir/myfile.csv", returnStdout: true).trim() 
}
```